# Vertically centering a text inside a SPAN

Tags: html, css

[image]

A text inside a `span` having less space on the `top` and more spaces in the `bottom` like the picture i specified above, and i dont know the reason why this is happening. My requirement is to display that text accurately center of that `span`. I have tried to set `margin-top`(`span` is an `inline` element and it wont support `margin-top`),`line-height` etc. But nothing seems to be working. And my question is can we vertically center a text inside a `span` accurately [ Equal spaces on `top` and `bottom` ].?

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DPfcq/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DPfcq/1/

Comment: @Ark The picture i specified was the magnified version of that fiddle. and also i had measured the space by using a virtual rule, the spaces were different.

Comment: try changing the font, to some non-serif, like tahoma.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DPfcq/6/ - line-height to be same as height of the span.

Comment: Or display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;

Comment: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can vertically center text inside a span accurately. You'll want to skim this, this article spells it out: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding-top and i hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately inline elements like span wont support padding-top. Please refer [this](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)